# What is the name of using lag explanatory variable in regressing on dependent variable?

Tags: econometrics, nonexpert

In general, we can run lag of response variable or lag of explanatory variable on regressand. The former (running lag of response variable on response variable is called auto-correlation), can I ask what is the name of the second regression (running lag of regressor on regressand)

Comment: Hi @Nguyen. My preference would be for you to just stick to the same terminology in such as small passage. Also - strictly speaking, persistence between $y_t(t =1,2... T)$ is only regarded as 'auto-correlation' when we normalised the coefficients on these terms.

Comment: @Nguyen Do you mean regressing $y_t$ on $x_t$ and $x_{t-1}$? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_lag

Comment: Hi: You've used three terms in your question: response variable, explanatory variable and regressand. I'm not sure which but one of them has to be redundant.

Comment: @markleeds regressand is synonym for response variable which are both synonyms for dependent variable

Comment: @chan1142 consider expanding your comment to an answer

Comment: @chan1142, thank you, I got the answer from your comment. But you can consider expand it to an answer that people can benefit from that. Thanks